# Printing a .NET DataGridView

Tags: winforms, printing, .net-3.5, datagridview

I am fairly new to .NET and C#, but I have a DataGridView that I would like to print.  What would be the best way to go about doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could export the DataGridView to Excel and then print it from Excel.

You could also consider to not show your data in a DataGridView, but show it in a ReportViewer control, which has the ability to export to PDF or Excel. From there it's possible to print your data.

Comment: @Bliek Thanks for the suggestion!  Like I mentioned in another comment, I'd like to try to stick with this control for now...  but I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: I ended up doing this, after all.  I still display my data in the DataGridView, but if the user chooses to print it I use a Report Viewer.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 13):

Add a DataGridView, a PrintDocuemnt, and a Button then:

```
button click events {
    printDocument1.Print();
}

printDocument1_PrintPage events {
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
    this.dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
}
```

That's all your data printing.

Comment: Not sure what I'm missing but this generates quite a few errors. I'm using visual studio 13 and c#.

Comment: This works great IF all your data is displayed in the DataGridView, as it only prints what's visible on the screen. If your data doesn't all fit within the borders of the DataGridView you don't get all the data. Still, very elegant and simple if that's all you ever need.

Comment: To overcome the problem pointed out by @DaveN59 I found I could set the Height of the DataGridView manually to (((RowCount - 1) * Rows[0].Height) + ColumnHeadersHeight) and hide the vertical scrollbar before calling DrawToBitmap. This prints the entire grid even though it is theoretically larger than the size of the containing window! Of course you must then restore Height to its previous value before returning.

Comment: private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
        {
Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height);
    this.dataGridView1.DrawToBitmap(bm, new Rectangle(0, 0, this.dataGridView1.Width, this.dataGridView1.Height));
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(bm, 0, 0);
        }

Answer (score 8):

There are projects on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/PrintDataGridView.aspx) that have done some work printing DataGridViews.

Answer (score 5):

I know you've already accepted an answer, but for the next person to search this question...

I also found this wonderful project on Code Project, and just implemented it.  It was EASY and nice.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/GridDrawer.Net.aspx

Answer (score 5):

On [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com):

> > [Another DataGridView Printer by aureolin](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/DGVPrinter.aspx)

Above is another excellent `DataGridView` Printer that is extremely simple to implement.

I realize I am a *Johnny Come Lately* to this thread. I stumbled upon it while searching for something else, but wanted to reference this excellent printing solution for others who happen by this way (as I did).

I hope someone here gets some use out of it.

Answer (score 3):

There is no built-in print support I'm afraid.

You might resort to using a third party control such as the [Infragistics WinGrid](http://www.infragistics.com/dotnet/netadvantage/winforms/wingrid.aspx#Overview) which has build-in support for printing.

Comment: @Gerrie Schenck Thanks for the link!  I think for now I'll keep pushing to try to use the current control, but I'll keep this in mind incase I need it!

Answer (score 2):

.NET WinForm controls (like the datagridview) do not natively support being printed.

In the case of the datagridview, though, you can call 'DrawToBitmap', and then take that bitmap and pass it on to the printing functions in order to produce it on paper.

Comment: @GWLlosa Thanks!  This works and I'm able to print my grid, but it comes out looking like a screenshot.  I was hoping to be able to format it in to something a little bit more friendly looking.  Thoughts?

Comment: If you want to reformat the way it looks, you either need to reformat the control itself before the call, or actually 'build your own' datagridview in drawing code, using the data in the rows and cells to populate it.  Gets messy quick.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to be printing more than just DataGridViews, then a more generic approach may be worth pursuing. We use MigraDoc and then wrote our own class to read DataGridViews and output MigraDoc classes representing a table.

There are lots of great printing packages available, but I only have experience with MigraDoc.

**Edit:**

In response to comments, here is a link to my site showing the code I created for generating MigraDoc tables and an example of using it to display a DataGridView ([DataGridView to MigraDoc tables](http://www.gowland.ca/printing-tables-with-migradoc)).

Comment: Hi there. Can you share some code samples that use Migradoc with DataGridViews?

Comment: Updated my answer with a link.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I like this method http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/GridDrawer.Net.aspx But is there any way I can choose the printer.

I want to auto print at the end of a process. So planing to choose this as options 1, so i can always print to default printer. And another option like to choose the printer and then print. So in total 2 ptint function in all. 
Please reply.
Cheers