# How to print dataGridview

Tags: datagridview

How to print All data from datagridview in vb.net.

Comment: Also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561174/c-printing-a-net-datagridview

+1 galwegian that dataGridViewPrinter is useful

Answer (score 5):

See the excellent [DataGridViewPrinter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/datagridviewprinter.aspx) on Codeproject.