# What's the best method to print from my C# program?

Tags: c#, winforms, printing

I have written a winform program that gathers information from several database tables and displays this information in a datagridview.  The user likes it a lot, but they've requested an additional feature: the ability to print the information in the datagridview to their printer.

All of the data that the user wants to print is in the datagridview.  If you had to make this kind of change to this program, what method would you use to get the information to the printer?

Comment: Might want to check: [C# - Printing a .NET DataGridView](http://stackoverflow.com/q/561174/719186)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=datagridview%20print&sbo=kw)'s got a bunch:

[The DataGridViewPrinter Class](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/datagridviewprinter.aspx)
[Printing of DataGridView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/PrintingOfDataGridView.aspx)
[Another DataGridView Printer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/DGVPrinter.aspx)
[Printing a DataGridView on DotNet Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/GridDrawer.Net.aspx)
[DataGridView Print/Print Preview Solution - Part I](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/GridPrintPreviewSolution.aspx)
[DataGridView Print/Print Preview Solution - Part II](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/printing/GridPrintPreviewSolution2.aspx)

Plus more.  I haven't tried any of these myself though.

Comment: Thanks for those links!  They've got me pointed in the right direction now.  I sure appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing that nicely, if you are able to, is create/design a local report (.rdlc) and print that report without showing the ReportViewer control. An example of that is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx).

Comment: Hey, that looks pretty interesting.  I'll check it out.  Thank you!